# Finding probability from average

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, average

This question may sound silly but I'm confused. If I have the information that on a network, 1 packet gets dropped out of every 30 packets on average. Can I say that the probability of getting a packet dropped is 1/30 and not getting dropped is 1-1/30?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise in order for any useful answer to be given here...

Comment: If the packets have equal probability to get dropped then each packet will have probability $\frac1{30}$ to be dropped.